# Angular http client module not displaying response

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I am trying to call an API(JSONPlaceholder posts API) in Angular 6 but am having an issue getting any results in my template

This is the api coming from a service file

```
  private _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  constructor( ) { }

  getBU() {
    return this._url;
  }
```

My ts component

```
  ngOnInit(): void { // adding the lifecycle hook ngOnInit
    this.http.get<DataResponse>(this.api.getBU()).subscribe(data => {
      this.vals = [data];
    });
  }
```

Interface to get certain values

```
export interface DataResponse {
    userId: string;
    id: string;
    title: string;
}
```

Template to display results

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of vals">
      {{item.title}}
  </li>
```

If I use this api `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` then I can see the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts url returns array of object and you are putting it into another array.

Please try the following:

```
  ngOnInit(): void { // adding the lifecycle hook ngOnInit
      this.http.get<DataResponse[]>(this.api.getBU()).subscribe(data => {
           this.vals = data;
      });
  }
```

Comment: If I do this I get an error ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. Which is why i made it an array

Comment: Did you change the get response from `DataResponse` to `DataResponse[]` ?